# Send a boolean from html to an AngularJS component

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have this html page:

```
<div class="first page">    
        <my-header title="Demand"></my-header>   
    <div class="my-nav">
    </div>  
    <div id="chart" class="demand-chart">
    </div>
</div>
```

This component:

```
const myHeader = {
    bindings: {
    title: '@',
    link: '@?'
    },
    controller: angular.noop,
    templateUrl: require('./myHeader.html')

}

export default myHeader;
```

which requires this template:

```
<div id="page-title">
    <div class="page-title-demand">{{$ctrl.title}}</div>
    <div class="bcrumb"> <a href="/#!/site_url">The Link!</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I want to do is to make the link optional, I'm using the component in multiple situations and some of the don't need the link. I've found out that adding `?` before the binding type makes that parameter optional.

Is there a way to write in the html page if the link is optional and show it on the page regarding the result of this statement?

Comment: In Angular, you don't "send" info from HTML to JS. You're taking the problem backwards. In Angular, JS constructs HTML. Therefore, if you don't want something to show up in the HTML, tell the JS no _not_ generate it in the first place, by setting some variable to `false`, and then toggling the tag with an `ng-if="variable"`. This is dynamic, of course, you can toggle the value at will.

Comment: use ng-if="$ctrl.link" in your html.

Comment: @nevradub I think it works as you said but I'm not sure how to add it. I done it like this: `<div ng-if="$ctrl.link" class="bcrumb"> <a href="/#!/site_url">The Link!</a></div>`. And in the html page probably something like this? `<my-header title="Demand" link=true></my-header> `

Comment: yes is good. And if you no need the link you just use this: <my-header title="Demand"></my-header>. Your property will be null so your ng if work.